Calculate Week Number of Year in T-SQL without DATEFIRST function or other database objects
I am working on a SaaS application that connects to a Microsoft SQL Server database, using T-SQL language.
I cannot develop stored procedures, user-defined functions, or any database objects.
I am developing a report using T-SQL language in my application; this report needs to generate week numbers (for a given year), using a Monday to Sunday week cycle, which obviously in not the default in Microsoft SQL Server.
I know that if I write,
SET DATEFIRST 1

it solves the problem.
Unfortunately, I cannot use DATEFIRST function either.
I can use a global variable such as @@DateFirst though.
I have a column called BusinessDate with date datatype in a table called dbo.BusinessInformation.
DATEPART(wk,BusinessDate) AS WeekNumberOfYear

How do I develop week number of a year in a Monday to Sunday week cycle, for the above BusinessDate column?
Any suggestion would be appreciated.
DECLARE @BusinessInformation TABLE ([BusinessDate] [date])

INSERT INTO @BusinessInformation

SELECT '2024-02-16'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2024-02-17'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2024-02-18'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2024-02-19'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2024-02-20'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2024-02-21'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2024-02-22'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2024-02-23'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2024-02-24'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2024-02-25'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2024-02-26'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2024-01-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2024-01-02'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2024-12-30'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2024-12-31'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2025-01-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2025-01-02'

SET DATEFIRST 7
--default--
--Sunday to Saturday week cycle--
--this CANNOT be changed in the SaaS application--

SELECT 
    BusinessDate, 
    DATENAME(dw, BusinessDate) AS WeekdayName,  
    DATEPART(wk,BusinessDate) AS ActualWeekNumberOfYear, 
    DATEADD(dd, -1, BusinessDate) AS SubtractDay, 
    DATEPART(wk,DATEADD(dd, -1, BusinessDate)) AS SubtractDayWeekNumberOfYear
FROM
    @BusinessInformation
ORDER BY 
    BusinessDate

In this code, SubtractDayWeekNumberOfYear works, but the start and/or tail of the year (Dec 31, Jan 1, etc.) have incorrect week numbers.
I need the output as below:
SET DATEFIRST 1
--Monday to Sunday week cycle--
--this is only for demonstration; I cannot change the DATEFIRST value 
--to 1 from 7, in the SaaS application--
--the output of the earlier T-SQL code must match that of this code; 
--that is the requirement of the project--
--in other words, I need to modify the former code to achieve the-- 
--output of this code--
  

SELECT  
    BusinessDate, 
    DATENAME(dw, BusinessDate) AS WeekdayName, 
    DATEPART(wk,BusinessDate) AS DATEFIRSTWeekNumberOfYear
FROM
    @BusinessInformation
ORDER BY 
    BusinessDate

I have even developed the below column:
(@@DateFirst + DatePart(weekday,BusinessDate) - 1) % 7 + 1

This gives me integer values from 1 to 7, but not sure how to develop week numbers using the 1 - 7 values.
Although this question looks pretty straightforward, and looks like someone has a solution in Stack Overflow already, that is not the case. I see a lot of similar posts, but not addressing my question directly!

Just calculate the week against an offset BusinessDate e.g. either dateadd(day,1,BusinessDate) or dateadd(day,-6,BusinessDate) depending whether you want to move Sunday forward, or the rest of the week back.

Tip: ( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1 will always return an integer from 1 to 7 with 1 corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of DateFirst or Language. You can jigger the constants to get a zero- or one-based value that starts on any day of the week.

I cannot use global variables such as @@DateFirst

DATEADD(dd, -1, BusinessDate) AS AddDay, DATEPART(wk,DATEADD(dd, -1, BusinessDate)) AS AddDayWeekNumberOfYear

the above code works, but January 1 and December 31, i.e. the start and tail of the year have problems

Use a case expression to detect and handle start and end of year.

Why can't you use global variables, does this SaaS thing have an own parser, the code being send should be able to use anything, but you should be able to figure out @@datefirst yourself using a known date and then use that expression

ok, i will try global variables too; i have not tried

@HABO
I am able to use global variables such as @@DateFirst in my SaaS application; so I can see the values 1 to 7 using ( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1; how do i get week numbers using 1 to 7 ?

@siggemannen   I am able to use global variables such as @@DateFirst in my SaaS application; so I can see the values 1 to 7 using ( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1; how do i get week numbers using 1 to 7 ?

i am able to add the below column into my query in my SaaS application:   ((@@DateFirst + DatePart(weekday,BusinessDate) - 1) % 7 + 1) AS DateFirstDerived

What next? Any idea

@Aaron Bertrand   I see a post in MS SQL Tips :  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7389/sql-date-calculations-simplified-first-last-nth-day-of-the-month/                  Can you look into this one ?

Generating week-of-year isn't straight forward. Two factors need to be decided. You may use ISO week numbering system if that matches your business requirements.
